# Laravel Routing a resourceful controller with parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have been using Resourceful controllers due to its simplicity. like so.

```
route('branches.create')
```

But my current business need requires i pass a specific parameter.

```
current/{company}/branches
```

how can I create a route to fit that kind of url. I have tried route('current.branches.create') and route('current.' . $id . 'branches.create')

Comment: Can you show us your routes? as these are just names inside of a helper function `route`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the route as `named routes` like:

```
Route::POST('current/{company}/branches', 'SomeController@somemethod')->name('branches.create');
```

and pass URL like:

```
<a href="{{route('branches.create', $company->id)}}">GOT TO URL</a>
```

More about [Larvel Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes)

Hope it's helpful.